# Alarm that requires a problem to be solved

Tags: apps, alarms

I have the habit of snoozing my alarm over and over, thus oversleeping often. I've seen some alarm apps on Android that make you solve a math problem / some puzzle before you can stop it. Are there similar apps for Windows Phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went to the Microsoft Store and just searched for "Alarm". There is an app called Tricky Alarm that does exactly what you are asking.

Comment: So did I, but must have missed it. Thanks.

Comment: @Vik glad I could help!